# Is there any way to connect android device to a credit / debit card reader and pass billing information?

Tags: android, credit-card, cardreader

So I have an android app for a shop, it stores information of products bought by customers, when customers are done shopping it calculates the total bill. Is there a way I could pass this bill information directly to card reader so the shop keeper dose not have to put it manually in the card reading machine? I would appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of the card reader.

Comment: You can try to use nfc module